# Pass object via parcelable or load from DB

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am practicing the MVVM model along with the Room and LiveData libraries. 
One implementation question bothers me is while I starting a new activity (for example, product list page to product detail page) whether should I pass my product object by implementing Parcelable or I could use ViewModel to load it from DB. I am not sure which one is better or could anyone compare the pros and cons between those two strategies? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the object's id to another activity. Then download the desired object from the Room database using the MVVM + LiveData.
2. I would recommend that you check this repo [google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture). You can find many popular library combinations for a simple project. **todo-mvvm-live** branch is right for you.